# Can't get mysql data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data to my view: model->controller->view.

my model:

```
class Records_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_records($array){

    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('records')->where('type', $array['type'])->get();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $data = array(
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "country" => $row['country'],
            "event" => $row['event'],
            "date" => $row['date'],
            "selection" => $row['selection'],
            "odds" => $row['odds'],
            "result" => $row['result']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
}
```

my controller function:

```
public function basketball(){
    $data = array(
        "type" => 1
    );

    $this->load->model('records_model');
    $data['records'] = $this->records_model->get_records($data);
    $this->load->view('basketball', $data);
}
```

and my view:

```
<?php foreach($records as $record){ ?>

                    <tr class="gradeA" id="id_65">
                        <td class="center"><?=$record['id'];?></td>
                        <td><?=$record['selection'];?></td>            
                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>
```

and after all I receive only nothing meaning numbers (1,1,1,2,4,R,N) so what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Check my answer. I did it more clear and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model like this:

**MODEL**

```
class Records_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_records($type){

    $this->db->select('*'); // write the column between select like select('id, selection')
    $this->db->where('type', $type);
    return $this->db->get('records')->$result_array();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function basketball(){
    $type = 1;

    $this->load->model('records_model');
    $data['records'] = $this->records_model->get_records($type);
    $this->load->view('basketball', $data);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php foreach($records as $record): ?>

    <tr class="gradeA" id="id_65">
        <td class="center"><?php echo $record['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php $record['selection']; ?></td>            
    </tr>

<?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Comment: @user2304363 If it works, I hope that you will accept the answer and voteup